# Legitimate uses of Object(o)

Tags: javascript, theory

When an object value is provided to the `Object` constructor, that value will be returned unchanged. So, given an object `obj`:

```
obj === new Object( obj )
```

and

```
obj === Object( obj )
```

Then, what's the point of doing `Object( obj )` in the first place? I can understand doing `Object( 'foo' )`, or `Object( 123 )` - it creates a wrapper object for the primitive value, but if we already have an object `obj`, why would we do `Object( obj )`?

Is this pattern useless?

Comment: Do you know that "obj" isn't a primitive?

Comment: @carlosfigueira My question is theoretical. Assuming that `obj` is an Object value, ...

Comment: @gdoron Mr. Curiosity `:)` (Wait, you code smileys, too?)

Comment: Guess you need to clarify what you mean by "an object `obj`". Do you mean an ["Object object"](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2)?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 I mean a value of the type Object http://es5.github.com/#x8.6

Comment: Ah right, I just realized it's defined: http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.3

Answer (score 4):

The comparison will check whether `obj` is a real object. It is nearly equivalent to checking for

```
typeof obj == "object"
```

Yet, that is also `true` for `null` and can lead to strange errors when we try to access its properties. So, instead of writing `if (typeof obj == "object" && obj !== null)` it is commonly shortened to `if (obj === Object(obj))`.

Also, it yields `true` for function objects as well, while the `typeof` test does not - but sometimes you want to allow everything that can hold properties, and someone will get angry on your lib if you forget functions.

So much about the pattern, Reid has written an excellent answer about the internals of `Object`, which explains the behaviour you already described in your question.

Comment: That's perfectly correct, but the assumption behind the question is that `obj` *be* an object (as per his comment on the question). There are definitely legitimate uses of the technique, but if you know (with ironclad certainty) that `obj` is an object, it is useless.

Comment: Yes, in that case the hole check is useless. But I missed other code snippets where the `Object` function was used, so I might have not understood the question.

Comment: @Bergi That is a fine example, I didn't know about that. I must admit that I screwed up with the wording of my question. I actually meant all usages of the `Object` constructor, regardless of the input type.

Comment: "it is commonly shortened" - Well, I have *never* seen this before and quite honestly I think that the other variant is more readable, even if (or because!) it's more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `obj` is an Object value, it will have no effect. Let's look at the specification for ES5 (yay!).

According to [§ 15.2.1.1 `Object([value])`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.1.1), if `obj` is not `null` or `undefined`, then we return `ToObject(value)`.

Now we turn our attention to [§ 9.9 ToObject](http://es5.github.com/#x9.9). It says that if the argument is of type Object, "the result is the input argument (no conversion)."

Hence, there is no theoretical reason to use `Object(obj)` where you *know* `obj` is an Object: it is the exact same as writing `obj`.

The other case you listed was `new Object(obj)`, which depends on [§ 15.2.2.1 `new Object([value])`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.2.1). It says that if `value` is supplied and the type of `value` is an Object, return `obj` if `obj` is a native ECMAScript object. If it is not native, then the result is implementation-defined (and therefore browser-dependent and *not recommended* to use, in my opinion).

Comment: Usually, when the question is about the usefulness of a certain feature, then it is expected that the answers provide usages of that feature, and therefore affirm its usefulness. Answers like "It's not useful" are not useful, because they rely on the experience of the answerer. There might exist usages that you don't know of...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Your comment on the question said "Assuming that `obj` is an Object value, ...". If you assume that `obj` is an Object value, then it *is* useless: the spec *proves* so. Unless one of the browsers has a broken implementation of the spec (which has certainly happened before, I concede: array literals with elided elements come to mind), there is no other possible answer given your constraints.

Comment: Just because it returns the input unchanged, does not mean that it's useless.

Comment: But it does. The two are algebraically equivalent. Assuming that `obj` is an object, `Object(obj)` is *identical* to just writing `obj`. And because `obj === obj` is true for all objects, you might as well just replace `obj === Object(obj)` with the `true`. So I suppose you could use the above statement as an alias for the boolean true.

Comment: What I meant is that the `Object` constructor behaves like an identity function for objects. I think that there are certainly usages for an identity function in JavaScript (or any language). This is only one example of a legitimate usage (I think), and there might be other usages as well.

Comment: I have found one usage - converting NodeList object to true arrays: `var arr = [].map.call( nodeList, Object );`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yes, I thought about that as soon as you said "identity function". But I don't think it will make a good use case, because it is equivalent to the slice function...

Comment: @Bergi Slice doesn't work in IE8/7 on node lists. This - `var arr = [].slice.call( nodeList, 0 );` - throws an error. That is why we need a different method and the code I posted above is the best solution I know of.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: OK, but they also don't implement Array.prototype.map, do they?

Comment: @Bergi No, but it's trivial to provide ES5-shim.