# Underscore.js _.isObject = function (obj) { return obj === Object(obj); };

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

When we view Underscore.js source code, we can see the following:

```
    _.isObject = function (obj) {
    return obj === Object(obj);
};
```

I know it works.

But why not use this:

```
    _.isObject = function(obj){
    return typeof obj ==="object";
};
```

?

Comment: Because `typeof null` is `'object'`.

Comment: Good one. But why do you post the answer as a comment?

Comment: @turboHz: Because I was too busy to write/explain a full answer ;)

Comment: why not `return obj instanceof Object`?

Comment: @JasonNichols: Because things such as `Object.create(null)` or objects from other environments (frames) are not `instanceof Object`, but are objects nonetheless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Legitimate uses of Object(o)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586673/legitimate-uses-of-objecto)

Comment: Good call, @Bergi. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why not use `typeof obj === "object"`

Because that's not what we wanted to test. The `_.isObject` function is supposed to return whether the argument is a reference value (i.e. an object, to which you can add properties) and whether it is not a primitive value.

The [`typeof` operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3) is not reliable for that. It yields `"object"` for the value `null` as well, and does not yield `"object"` for callable objects (i.e. functions).

Instead, we can use the [`Object` function](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.1.1) which will try to "cast" its argument to an object via [ToObject](http://es5.github.io/#x9.9), and will yield the argument exactly in the case when it already is an object.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is with the tricky value `null`. `typeof null` returns `'object'`, which is obviously quite confusing and not the desired result.

However, using the object constructor with `null` results in the creation of a new object  (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)). This means that you can distinguish between objects and `null`, which `typeof` cannot do.

Comment: `null` is not the only value which leads to a wrong result.